# Trying to get an alert to show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get an alert box to print out the temperature as stored in the arrays, depending on the day of the week (0-6), but nothing is happening.

Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
var highTemps = ["32", "41", "36", "29", "39", "37", "40"];
var lowTemps = ["18", "24", "20", "27", "30", "31", "27"];


    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();


    if(n == 0){
        alert("Expect a high of " highTemps[0] " and a low of " lowTemps[0] " today.");

    }else if(n == 1){
       alert ("Expect a high of" highTemps[1] "and a low of" lowTemps[1] "today.");

    }else if(n == 2){
       alert("Expect a high of" highTemps[2] "and a low of" lowTemps[2] "today.");

    }else if(n == 3){
       alert("Expect a high of" highTemps[3] "and a low of" lowTemps[3] "today.");

    }else if(n == 4){
       alert("Expect a high of" highTemps[4] "and a low of" lowTemps[4] "today.");

    }else if(n == 5){
       alert("Expect a high of" highTemps[5] "and a low of" lowTemps[5] "today.");

    }else if(n == 6){
       alert("Expect a high of" highTemps[6] "and a low of" lowTemps[6] "today.");

    }else {
        alert("Who knows what the temperature is?!");
    };


    console.log("The average temperature for this week is [average].");
    console.log("The warmest day of the week will have a high temperature of [hTemperature]");
    console.log("The lowest low temperature of the week will be [lTemperature].)");
```

Comment: Missing `+` in all of the alerts..`alert("Expect a high of " + highTemps[0]  + " and a low of " + lowTemps[0]  + " today.");`

Comment: And I would just write `alert("Expect a high of " + highTemps[n] + " and a low of " + lowTemps[n] + " today.");` instead of that whole `if else` construction.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you need to concatenate the static portions of the message with the dynamic portions with the `+` operator:

```js
var highTemps = ["32", "41", "36", "29", "39", "37", "40"];
var lowTemps = ["18", "24", "20", "27", "30", "31", "27"];

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

if(n == 0){
  alert("Expect a high of " + highTemps[0] + " and a low of " + lowTemps[0] + " today.");
}else if(n == 1){
  alert ("Expect a high of" + highTemps[1] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[1] + "today.");
}else if(n == 2){
  alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[2] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[2] + "today.");
}else if(n == 3){
  alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[3] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[3] + "today.");
}else if(n == 4){
  alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[4] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[4] + "today.");
}else if(n == 5){
  alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[5] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[5] + "today.");
}else if(n == 6){
  alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[6] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[6] + "today.");
}else {
  alert("Who knows what the temperature is?!");
};

console.log("The average temperature for this week is [average].");
console.log("The warmest day of the week will have a high temperature of [hTemperature]");
console.log("The lowest low temperature of the week will be [lTemperature].)");
```

Now, having said that, we can simplify your code by just using the `n` variable as the index to the arrays and get rid of all that `if/then`.

Also, with the type of if/then you have a `switch` statement can be more concise:

```js
var highTemps = ["32", "41", "36", "29", "39", "37", "40"];
var lowTemps = ["18", "24", "20", "27", "30", "31", "27"];

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

// If the array contains an index of the current day number
if(highTemps.indexOf(n) > -1){
  // Just extract that element from the arrays and use it.
  alert("Expect a high of " + highTemps[n] + " and a low of " + lowTemps[n] + " today.");
} else {
  // Otherwise, show the default message
  alert("Who knows what the temperature is?!");
}

console.log("The average temperature for this week is [average].");
console.log("The warmest day of the week will have a high temperature of [hTemperature]");
console.log("The lowest low temperature of the week will be [lTemperature].)");
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still not getting any alert boxes popping up overall on the page.

Comment: @whxtn3y You need to check your developer's console (F12 in your browser and click the Console tab) to see if you have other errors in your code. As you can see in my answer, it does work.

Comment: Tinkered around with it & it eventually worked. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @whxtn3y You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote the answer and mark it as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in alert function. String message should be append with array value using '+'.

```
<script>
var highTemps = ["32", "41", "36", "29", "39", "37", "40"];
var lowTemps = ["18", "24", "20", "27", "30", "31", "27"];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

if(n == 0){ 
   alert("Expect a high of " + highTemps[0] +" and a low of " +lowTemps[0] + " today.");

}else if(n == 1){
   alert ("Expect a high of" + highTemps[1] + "and a low of" +lowTemps[1] + "today.");

}else if(n == 2){
   alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[2] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[2] + "today.");

}else if(n == 3){
   alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[3] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[3] + "today.");

}else if(n == 4){
   alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[4] + "and a low of" +lowTemps[4]+ "today.");

}else if(n == 5){
   alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[5] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[5] + "today.");

}else if(n == 6){
   alert("Expect a high of" + highTemps[6] + "and a low of" + lowTemps[6] + "today.");

}else {
    alert("Who knows what the temperature is?!");
};


console.log("The average temperature for this week is [average].");
console.log("The warmest day of the week will have a high temperature of [hTemperature]");
console.log("The lowest low temperature of the week will be [lTemperature].)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is the missing `window` for the `window.alert`, also you could use ES6 syntax to avoid using `+` at all:

```js
const highTemps = ["32", "41", "36", "29", "39", "37", "40"];
const lowTemps = ["18", "24", "20", "27", "30", "31", "27"];
const d = new Date();
const n = d.getDay();

if(n === 0) {
  window.alert(`Expect a high of ${highTemps[0]} and a low of ${lowTemps[0]} today.`);
} else if(n === 1) {
  window.alert (`Expect a high of ${highTemps[1]} and a low of ${lowTemps[1]} today.`);
} else if(n === 2) {
  window.alert (`Expect a high of ${highTemps[2]} and a low of ${lowTemps[2]} today.`);
} else if(n === 3) {
  window.alert (`Expect a high of ${highTemps[3]} and a low of ${lowTemps[3]} today.`);
} else if(n === 4) {
  window.alert (`Expect a high of ${highTemps[4]} and a low of ${lowTemps[4]} today.`);
} else if(n === 5) {
  window.alert (`Expect a high of ${highTemps[5]} and a low of ${lowTemps[5]} today.`);
} else if(n === 6) {
  window.alert (`Expect a high of ${highTemps[6]} and a low of ${lowTemps[6]} today.`);
} else {
  alert("Who knows what the temperature is?!");
};


console.log("The average temperature for this week is [average].");
console.log("The warmest day of the week will have a high temperature of [hTemperature]");
console.log("The lowest low temperature of the week will be [lTemperature].)");
```

Or you could even:

```js
const highTemps = ["32", "41", "36", "29", "39", "37", "40"];
const lowTemps = ["18", "24", "20", "27", "30", "31", "27"];
const d = new Date();
const n = d.getDay();

for (let i = 0; i < highTemps.length; i++) {
  if  (n === i) {
    window.alert(`Expect a high of ${highTemps[i]} and a low of ${lowTemps[i]} today.`);  
  } 

  if (n >= 7) {
    window.alert("Who knows what the temperature is?!");
  }
}

console.log("The average temperature for this week is [average].");
console.log("The warmest day of the week will have a high temperature of [hTemperature]");
console.log("The lowest low temperature of the week will be [lTemperature].)");
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to former comments your code ends with "< /script>". There is a space between "<" and "/".

Comment: That space is not illegal in HTML, so it's fine that way.